# Rendering Partial View in a div dynamically in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a list of link buttons(l1,l2,l3..etc) and a fixed div area.when I click l1 for example partialview1 will populate within div and when I click l2 for example partialview2 will populate within the same div replacing existing partialview1.Each partial view has different model.
My Code is given below: SettingsMaster.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ManageSettings";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
}
@section JavaScript
{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/SettingsCustomScript.js")"></script>
}
<h2>ManageSettings</h2>
@Html.ActionLink("Area", null, null, null, new {@id="Area", @style = "text-transform:capitalize;" })
@Html.ActionLink("Subarea", null, null, null, new {@id="SubArea", @style = "text-transform:capitalize;" })

<div id="Datadisplay"></div>
```

Java Script Code:Custom Javascript file

```
/// <reference path="jquery-1.8.3.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery-1.5.1-vsdoc.js" />

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#Area").click(function () {


        $("#Datadisplay").load('/Settings/GetArea', null, function (response, status, xhr) {

            if (status == "error") {

                alert("An error occured");
            }

            return false;

        });





    });

    $("#Subarea").click(function () {
        alert("hello");

    }

    );
```

Controller Method:

```
public class SettingsController : Controller { // // GET: /Settings/
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ManageSettings()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetArea()
    {
        return PartialView("GetArea");

    }


}
```

But when it is rendering it is calling ManageSettings() this is why it is not showing. Plz help me what to do

Comment: What have tried? What problems have you encountered during the implementation of this feature?

Answer (score 0):

I read this in another post in stack overflow and it worked for me

in the View:

```
    @model Tuple<IEnumerable<Model1name>,Model2name>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Item1)
    {
        @item.Name
    }
```

In the Controller:

```
    var tuple = new Tuple<IEnumerable<Model1name>, Model2name>(context.Model1name.ToList(), new Model2name());
    return View(tuple);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a simple jquery call.

On the click of your link buttons you do a $.Get(...) and render the partialview returned by your controller